# Load PDF as background - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to write an android application that will load a PDF as a background so that I can add some extra information on top of it without modifying the actual PDF. I am new to Android development and I been having a lot of trouble with this. I need to find a way to somehow open a PDF and then start a new transparent activity on top of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a FrameLayout, place a View containing your PDF on background, and everything you want to be on top of it - on foreground. Good luck!